# Mysql BEFORE UPDATE Trigger for changes to many (but not all) columns on large table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a large table with about 80 columns with an identical archive table for storing previous records that have been changed. The vast majority of the 80 columns are meaningful and we want to trigger an archive of the row so that we can build a history of changes to the record, but a handful of columns are not worthy of triggering an archive entry (timestamps, comments, etc.).

For most of these types of triggers, we just compare the values (**OLD.column1 <=> NEW.column1 || OLD.column2 <=> NEW.column2 || ...**) for all relevant columns, but this would be an extremely large list and has to be changed every time a new column is added or removed.

Is there any other way to create a trigger that will allow us to capture changes to a row EXCEPT for a few columns we want to ignore?

Comment: 60 columns are really a lot, can't you split the tables in useful and not useful the insert and update would take 2 inserts but you don't onöly think about when you add a column where it belongs

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately, the "not useful" columns are meta data and cannot be separated. Example, one of the columns we want the trigger to ignore is an updated_at timestamp handled by the framework. It must be there and it gets touched each time a poller updates this table, even if no data changed. This is a primary example of a row change that should NOT trigger an archive, but can't be dropped or moved to another table.

Comment: you can have more than one table for a row linked by an id in an 1:1 relationship, so it doesn't matter where you uodate_at column is as all rows from the tables are linked, the only thing is you have to change ypour code as you have to join the second table when you need the information

Comment: Interesting concept and one to think about, but would be a significant departure from our framework's design and would cause more work than it would prevent. Details - the framework adds created_at and updated_at timestamp fields to every table is manages. When pollers see the same data on a polling cycle, only the timestamps are updated so our code knows that data is still there and unchanged. That should not create an archive entry, but removing that field would break the framework's ability to manage that table.

Comment: columns and rows should never be deleted, that always would cause problems with foreign keys and queries. When columns allow Null , the don't cost nay space

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will return the second maximum salary, integer attribute, from the Employees table, where the table schema is Employees(eid, ename, dno, job, salary). You have to use CURSOR to solve this task.

Comment: did you mean stored procedure instead of function?

Answer (score 0):

2. Create a trigger that will archive the update process on the customer s' balance, in Customer table, only into the BalanceUpdate table. The trigger will not archive any update of the other attributes in the Customer table. For your solution consider the following schemas:

- Customer(cid, cname, caddress, accountNo, accountType, balance)
- BalanceUpdate(user, updateTime, cid, accountNo, oldBalance, newBalance)